# Between conditional join with LinQ

Tags: vb.net, linq, join

I'm trying to write the LinQ of following T-SQL

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.Customers c
inner join dbo.AgeGroups
ON  AgeGroups.FromAge<= c.Age and c.Age< AgeGroups.ToAge
```

But it seems there is no way to have conditional join in LinQ

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging into LinQ I find the solution:

```
 q = (From p In db.Customers
      From a In db.AgeGroups
      Where p.Age.HasValue AndAlso (a.FromAge <= p.Age AndAlso a.ToAge > p.Age))
```